# React firebase doesn't await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from firebase and map it and render a table with it but the firebase function returns data after the page loads.

```
    const [datas, setData] = useState();
    var ref = db.ref("something");

  
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        await ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
          const fetched = snapshot.val();
          var feed = {'name':'shoe','remark':'remarka','price':'pricea','photo':'photo','amount':'350'};
          console.log('fetched', fetched)
          setData(feed);
        }); 
      };
      fetchData();
    }, []);
```

now if I make a var here
let's say var text= datas
and console.log it it will return undefined
the feed var is just some dummy text

```
{dummy.map((data, key) => {
//render table
})
```

is there any way to make the page wait for the function to finish the useState ?

Comment: Am i wrong or you are throwing away you api response?  I see you call `setData` passing the const `feed` you manually created instead of `fetched`.  And where are you trying to print the `datas` value? 
Since you are using the setter (`setData`) inside the `.then()`, you are already awaiting for the fetch to complete before updating the state.    If you say that datas never get updated, i guess you db call is failing (so no .then() callback is called, just the .catch() but you don't have it defined).   Are you sure your fetch is resolving correctly?   Is the `fetched` console.log get printed?

Comment: yes it is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AND operator (&&) which only executes the right operand when the left operand is truthy. It is not necessary to make a variable called dummy.

```
{
  datas && datas.map(data=>{
     console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: i get this     Uncaught TypeError: datas.map is not a function

Comment: I think it's because you don't set and initial state for your `datas`. By using `useState()` without the initial value, the datas will be `undefined` before you set a new value (after your fetch) and typescript, assume the type is undefined.  if you want to init as undefined, do `useState<undefined | yourType>(undefined)`, of initialize the state like `useState([])` (if you will use it for an array) (so typescript will not think you are trying to access `.map` on `undefined`.

Comment: The map method needs an array to iterate. You are passing a hard coded object inside the setData() and it expects an array of objects. That is why it is showing that error. Can you try setData(fetched) instead, for that will give you the data from firebase. I don't know the reason behind the feed variable though. Tell me if you have any further issues :)